# Fast way of calculating number of consecutive nan values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to transform my dataframe so that the new DataFrame is of the same shape where each entry represents the number of consecutive NaNs counted after its position as follows:

IN:

```
    A       B      
0   0.1880  0.345 
1   0.2510  0.585  
2   NaN     NaN  
3   NaN     NaN 
4   NaN     1.150  
5   0.2300  1.210  
6   0.1670  1.290  
7   0.0835  1.400  
8   0.0418  NaN    
9   0.0209  NaN    
10  NaN     NaN    
11  NaN     NaN    
12  NaN     NaN
```

OUT:

```
    A       B      
0   0       0    
1   0       0  
2   3       2  
3   2       1 
4   1       0  
5   0       0 
6   0       0 
7   0       0 
8   0       5    
9   0       4   
10  3       3   
11  2       2 
12  1       1
```

Similar question that I was trying to modify - [Fast way to get the number of NaNs in a column counted from the last valid value in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517953/fast-way-to-get-the-number-of-nans-in-a-column-counted-from-the-last-valid-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform a reverse cumulative sum on a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541618/perform-a-reverse-cumulative-sum-on-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52718619/3275464

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """    A       B      
0   0.1880  0.345 
1   0.2510  0.585  
2   NaN     NaN  
3   NaN     NaN 
4   NaN     1.150  
5   0.2300  1.210  
6   0.1670  1.290  
7   0.0835  1.400  
8   0.0418  NaN    
9   0.0209  NaN    
10  NaN     NaN    
11  NaN     NaN    
12  NaN     NaN    """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), engine='python', sep='\s+')

_df = df.isna().iloc[::-1]
b = _df.cumsum()
c = b.sub(b.mask(_df).ffill().fillna(0)).astype(int).iloc[::-1]
c #gives the output you seem to want
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way to transform your DataFrame by counting the consecutive NaN values after each position in each column and replacing the NaN values with the count.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the input DataFrame
data = {
    'A': [0.1880, 0.2510, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.2300, 0.1670, 0.0835, 0.0418, 0.0209, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'B': [0.345, 0.585, np.nan, np.nan, 1.150, 1.210, 1.290, 1.400, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize counters
counters = {col: 0 for col in df.columns}

# Transform the DataFrame
for col in df.columns:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if pd.isna(df.at[i, col]):
            counters[col] += 1
            df.at[i, col] = counters[col]
        else:
            counters[col] = 0

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
tmp = df.notna()

out = tmp.apply(lambda s: s[::-1].groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
               ).mask(tmp, 0)[::-1]
```

Output:

```
    A  B
0   0  0
1   0  0
2   3  2
3   2  1
4   1  0
5   0  0
6   0  0
7   0  0
8   0  5
9   0  4
10  3  3
11  2  2
12  1  1
```